# Graphic bug on Safari when I hover over a button

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a graphic bug on Safari (mac) when I hover over a button. After I hover over the button, a brown background or something like that appears. It only happens in Safari. In other browsers there is no issue.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Safari

[image: Safari]

Chrome

[image: chrome]

```
.btn-pulse{
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
background-color: #323b44 !important;
}

.btn-pulse:hover{
color: #fff;
background-color: #2d363e !important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

**Update:**

It only happens when i have the website on 100%, if i zoom in or out is everything okay. No brown background.

Comment: Can you provide the code? It would be a lot easier to see where the issue is.

Comment: I updated the post, now it it includes the styles.

Except the height and width, cause i'm yousing bootstrap, so it's has the default style. 'btn-default'

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: I could, but it looks like that it's a safari bug.

When i zoom into the site is everything okay, only on 100%, so no zoom in or out happens that